# Eigen3 JacobiSVD different singular values depending on compiler flags

Tags: c++, eigen3, svd

I'm using Eigen3 version 3.3.1 and g++ version (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0. I'm finding that I get different results from JacobiSVD::singularValues(), depending on whether -march=native is part of the compile command. It seems as though the actual significant flag within the "-march=native" umbrella is -mavx. Here is a test case:

```
using dictionary_t = Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::ColMajor>;
const float halfroot = std::sqrt(2.0f)/2.0f;

Eigen::Matrix<float, 37, 38, Eigen::ColMajor> m;
m << 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, halfroot,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -halfroot,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1;
Eigen::JacobiSVD<dictionary_t> svdDi{m, Eigen::ComputeFullU|Eigen::ComputeFullV};
Eigen::VectorXf singVals = svdDi.singularValues();
Eigen::IOFormat fmt{Eigen::StreamPrecision, Eigen::DontAlignCols, ", "};
std::cout << "singular values of m: \n" << std::setprecision(10)
          << singVals.format(fmt) << std::endl;
```

And here is its output without -march=native set:

```
singular values of m:
1.84775877
1.000000238
1.000000119
1.000000119
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999998808
0.9999998212
0.7653669715
```

If I compile with -march=native, the first couple of singular values are different:

```
singular values of m:
1.847759128
1.000000119
1.000000119
1.000000119
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.9999999404
0.7653669715
```

Sorry about the bulkiness of my example. So, is this expected behavior? If so, is there a reason to prefer one result over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These Eigen values are close enough that they can be considered as identical (especially for `float`).
Eigen can use a different set of intrinsics depending on the flags, so the computation order can be different, and of course [floating point math is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

All these numbers are close enough compared to machine precision and the size and type of your matrix.

Comment: If I change the numeric type in my example from float to double, the differences in singular values are too small to show up, given the precision I'm setting for output. This adds support to your answer.

Comment: I didn't even notice that you were using `float`. Don't look further, the machine epsilon for them is around the numerical differences you have.